# Counting the number of observations by groups with conditions in R

Tags: r, count

I would like to count the number of observations within each group using conditions in R.

For example, I would like to count how many observations for ID "A" in every 10 days.

```
ID (A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A)
Day (7,14,17,25,35,37,42,57)
X (9,20,14,24,23,30,20,40)
```

Output Image
(In the first 10 days, we have one observation for ID "A". Days:7
 In the next 10 days, we have two observations for ID "A". Days:14,17)

```
ID (A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A)
Day_10 (1,2,3,4,5,6)
Count_10 (1,2,1,2,1,1)
```

Also it would be great if I can calculate the number of observations before and after the certain values. For the given X value, I would like to know how many observation between [X-10, X+10] within ID "A".

The output image would be as follows:

```
ID (A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A)
X (9,20,14,24,23,30,40,50)
Count_X10 (3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1)
```

Count_X10: for a given X(=9) there are three observations within ID "A" [-1,19]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the data loaded as a data.frame to keep the observations connected. Note that I added a second group to to show how to handle that

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    ID = rep(c("A","B"), each = 8)
    , Day = c(7,14,17,25,35,37,42,57)
    , X = c(9,20,14,24,23,30,20,40)
  )
```

Then, I used `dplyr` to pass the data through a series of steps. First, I split by the `ID` column, then used `lapply` to run a function on each of those `ID` groups, including calculating two columns of interest (then returning the whole data.frame). Finally, I stitch the rows back together with `bind_rows`

```
df %>%
  split(.$ID) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    x$nextTen <- sapply(x$Day, function(thisDay){
      sum(between(x$Day, thisDay, thisDay + 10))
    })

    x$plusMinusTen <- sapply(x$Day, function(thisDay){
      sum(between(x$Day, thisDay - 10, thisDay + 10))
    })

    return(x)
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

The result is

```
   ID Day  X nextTen plusMinusTen
1   A   7  9       3            3
2   A  14 20       2            3
3   A  17 14       2            4
4   A  25 24       2            3
5   A  35 23       3            4
6   A  37 30       2            3
7   A  42 20       1            3
8   A  57 40       1            1
9   B   7  9       3            3
10  B  14 20       2            3
11  B  17 14       2            4
12  B  25 24       2            3
13  B  35 23       3            4
14  B  37 30       2            3
15  B  42 20       1            3
16  B  57 40       1            1
```

But any condition you are interested good be added to that `lapply` step.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data :

```
df = data.frame(
  ID = rep('A', 8),
  Day = c(7, 14, 17, 25, 35, 37, 42, 57),
  X = c(9, 20, 14, 24, 23, 30, 40, 50),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

*Note*: You give two different values for vector `X`. I suppose it is `c(9, 20, 14, 24, 23, 30, 40, 50)`, and not `c(9, 20, 14, 24, 23, 30, 20, 40)`.

### First calculation:

```
library(dplyr)

output1 = df %>% 
  mutate(Day_10 = ceiling(Day/10)) %>%
  group_by(ID, Day_10) %>%
  summarise(Count_10 = n())
```

The `mutate` step creates the ranges of 10 days by rounding `Day/10`. Then we group by `ID` and `Day_10` and we count the number of observations within each group.

```
> output1
     ID Day_10 Count_10
  <chr>  <dbl>    <int>
1     A      1        1
2     A      2        2
3     A      3        1
4     A      4        2
5     A      5        1
6     A      6        1
```

### Second calculation:

```
output2 = df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Count_X10 = sapply(X, function(x){sum(Day >= x-10 & Day <= x+10)})) %>%
  select(-Day)
```

We group by `ID`, and for each `X` we count the number of days with this `ID` that are between `X-10` and `X+10`.

```
> output2
     ID     X Count_X10
  <chr> <dbl>     <int>
1     A     9         3
2     A    20         3
3     A    14         3
4     A    24         3
5     A    23         3
6     A    30         3
7     A    40         3
8     A    50         2
```

*Note*: I suppose there's a mistake in the desired output you give, because for instance, when `X = 50`, there are 2 observations within [40, 60] with `ID` "A": days 42 and 57.